# flex-basis: 0 with overflow hidden adding space awkwardly

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying to temporarily hide some content out of view by transitioning flex and flex-basis properties.

The following link is an over simplified demonstration of the issue I'm having. See how the first item inherits the extra space...
http://codepen.io/mr_webster/pen/BWNWKo

```
<div class="box">
<div class="item first">item</div>
<div class="item second">
<p>item</p>
</div>
<div class="item third">
<p>item</p>
</div>
<div class="item forth">item</div>
</div>

.box {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
flex: 1 0 50%;
background: tomato;
overflow: hidden;
}

.first { flex: 0 0 100%; }
.second { flex: 0 0 0; }
.forth { flex: 0 0 100%; }
```

The second link here is more along the lines of what I'm trying to achieve, but still demonstrates the issue of extra space being added. http://codepen.io/mr_webster/pen/oZXBMd

Any suggestions as to why this is happening or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your second link, the space that's added after you click on the button is caused by the second div `<div class="item second">` because technically it is still part of the normal flow. The way around this is to 'remove' that second div after you click on the button. Make the following edits to your code:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: tomato; /*add background color to your .box. This is needed for animation reasons*/
}

.box.toggle {
  .second {
    flex: 0 1 0%;
    height: 0; /* This hides the second div and removes the space you're referring to.*/
  }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: As for a final state this definitely works, but the sudden gap created by this approach during the transition is what I'm trying to work around. I've had some success with transitioning max-height, while it seems to work it gives me some weird flickering during some of the rendering steps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution I came up with, though it feels hacky and I'd hoped for something more elegant. http://codepen.io/mr_webster/pen/mWJzRR

I'm transitioning max-height and transform on a container element.

```
<div class="item second">
  <div class="second-container">
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
  </div>
</div>

.second-container {
  transition-property: max-height, transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  max-height: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

second-container {
  max-height: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```